# Jquery Hover and Click in IE not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an array of blocks that are going to be created in a document. They serve as interaction points on a map. (Theres a map image as the background and the blocks are directly above houses on the map)

```
for(blocks.length)
   var newblock = $("<span data-unit='" + blocks[i].unitnum + "' class='unitwrap' />");
   ....
   newblock.click(function() {...});
   newblock.hover(function() {
      ....
   }, function () {
      ....
   });
}
```

In the event functions I add a background image to the span elements. Creating an effect when hovering over, or clicking on a house. This all works great...

Except in IE

Do these Jquery functions not work in IE (hover and click) or is it something else?

Comment: jQuery version?  IE version?  What are you doing with `newblock` after you create it?

Comment: you are also missing a { after your for declaration. You should post a fiddle , maybe you should write :
     for( var i in blocks.length )

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't have any semicolons - is that your actual code?

Comment: have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: maybe your css doesnt show up the span, so you cant hover it. `for` loop without limiter. you use `i`, its not defined somewhere here. jQuery selectors are **not** in `<..>` except you `.append()` that newblock element somewhere into your DOM right after, otherwise it cant apply the work after. `.hover()` and `.click()` need real selectors to bind the eventlisteners.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the span, i give CSS `display:inline-block` here with height and width.
After creating this `<span>` element with jQuery it is append somewhere in the DOM (here as example on `'body'`) so hover and click can interact with the browsers mousehandler (not visible elements do not fire mouseevents, logical ^^ ), 
after i pack your allready given `newblock` element as selector to jQuery `$(newblock)` to help its lookup mechanism to know where to bind the EventListener to in the DOM

*you cant bind eventListeners direct to `document.createElement('span')` which is equivalent to `$('<span />')`, you allways need to put it somewhere in your DOM for, in other words, you cant bind listeners to javascript itsself (variables), but to objects in the dom*

And just to check out the object structure of `blocks` i made tiny example of it.

```
<style>
  .unitwrap {height:40px; width:40px; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #f00}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var blocks=[{"unitnum":2},{"unitnum":4}];
   var l=blocks.length;
   for (var i=0;i<l;i++) {
       var newblock = $("<span data-unit='" + blocks[i].unitnum + "' class='unitwrap' />");
       $('body').append(newblock);
       $(newblock).click(function(){
         console.log('yeah clicked');
       });
       $(newblock).hover(function(){
         console.log('plop hovered');
       });
   }
</script>
```